# Get all subfolders and their size

Tags: c#-4.0, combobox

I am trying to write a method.

```
public List<string> getList()
{
    string[] str;
    string no, name, size, price;
    string albumFolder = @"F:\Audio";
    char a = ' ';

    List<string> albums = new List<string>();

    albumFolder.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
    str = albumFolder.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);

        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            string n = str[i].ToString();
            n = n.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).ToString();
            no = (i > 8 ? "  " : "    ") + (i + 1) + "".PadRight(10, a);
            name = n.PadRight((155 - n.Length), a);
            size = "" + 512 + " MB".PadRight(20, a); // also help me finding their size
            price = "" + 80 + "".PadRight(10, a);
            albums.Add(no + name + size + price);
        }
    return albums;
}
```

this method will return a `List` so that I can do this:

```
albumList.DataSource = getList(); //albumList is a ComboBox
```

This `List` should contain strings that are fixed length with all the subsfolder's name(not location, name only). But it doing as the picture:

[image]
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you may be looking for (although I agree there are better/easier ways):

```
public List<string> getList()
        {
            string no, name, size, price;
            string albumFolder = @"F:\Audio";
            char a = ' ';

            List<string> albums = new List<string>();

            string[] str = Directory.GetDirectories(albumFolder);

            for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            {
                DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(str[i]);
                no = (i > 8 ? "  " : "    ") + (i + 1) + "".PadRight(10, a);
                name = info.Name.PadRight(155, a);
                size = "" + 512 + " MB".PadRight(20, a); // also help me finding their size
                price = "" + 80 + "".PadRight(10, a);
                albums.Add(no + name + size + price);
            }
            return albums;
        }
```

Comment: Yes this is. But Size and Price columns aren't correctly aligned. See the [pic](http://www.4shared.com/photo/Pwrbq2g0/a_2.html)

Comment: Hi Brian, yeah, you'll need to use a monotype font/fixed width font to achieve the look you want.  Also, I fixed a small typo in the answer around the "name" field -- you don't want to subtract the length from the padding.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Change [`List<String>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) to [`BindingList<String>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx)

```
public BindingList<string> getList()
{
    ...
   return new BindingList<string>(albums);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very complex and does not have to be. Please use Directory and Path classes i.e. Path.GetDirectoryName and don't parse by hand.

Here is some code to walk files in a pre-NET4 way:

```
/// <summary>
/// Walks all file names that match the pattern in a directory
/// </summary>
public static IEnumerable<string> AllFileNamesThatMatch(this string fromFolder, string pattern, bool recurse)
{
  return Directory.GetFiles(fromFolder,
                     pattern,
                     recurse ? SearchOption.AllDirectories :
                               SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
}

/// <summary>
/// Walks all file names in a directory
/// </summary>
public static IEnumerable<string> AllFileNames(this string fromFolder, bool recurse)
{
  return fromFolder.AllFileNamesThatMatch("*.*", recurse);
}
```

You can get sizes by walking the IEnumerable using Sum<> LINQ

Answer (score 0):

remove the below line from your code and all works fine.

```
n = n.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).ToString();
```